# Common security holes specific to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I am a fairly novice Rails developer but because most things in Rails are so easy, I'm always afraid I'm adding a new security hole when I write my code. For example, just an hour ago I spotted one in code I wrote a few weeks ago, where in the edit method of UsersController I forgot to check if the user you are editing was equal to the user you are logged in as (i.e. `@user = User.find params[:id]` instead of `@user = current_user`). I wrote it like this because I normally use it for all edit methods (e.g. `@post = Post.find params[:id]`). This would show you the email adress of another user.

What are common security holes in Rails apps I should be aware of? Things that are overlooked easily due to conventions (like the example above)?

Answer (score 2):

Common sense problems like you illustrated are probably the most important security problems. Rails has come a long way in creating a more secure framework, for example SQL injection which plagues many PHP applications is covered (for the most part) by sanitized form input that is now default. The official word on Rails security is a good read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: Pointless jab at another language when common PHP frameworks do the same thing. PHP is a language, Rails is a framework.

Comment: @Dan Grossman I agree, I can use ADODB and PDO and stop all sql injection.  I can stop all XSS with a templating system.  Or just install a WAF on any platform and make it very difficult to find and exploit these issues.   (@seeingidog +1 for the ruby security doc,  it is a good read.)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I do after creating a new controller is to set up a functional test that ensures the user can only do stuff they're supposed to do. In your example, the test should assert that users are only allowed to edit their own account details, whereas administrators should be able to edit other accounts as well.

Using this approach you can also verify that you don't break anything during refactoring, which in turn prevents you from accidentally re-opening security holes later on in the project.

You might find the following useful:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html